# Json data is not getting serialized correctly in the action method in web api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post the below data to my action method in json format and trying to accepting the JSon data to get automatically serialized to my typed class but it is not happening. can any please tell where I am going wrong?

Header :

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:62813
Content-Length: 103
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

Action Method in Web API:

```
 public void Post([FromBody]Book value)
 {

 }
```

Input Json Data :

```
{
"Title": "asasd",
"Author": "asaa",
"Publisher": "Asaas",
"Category": "asdasd",
"Price": "12"
}
```

Model :

```
public class Book : Product
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Title is required")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Author is required")]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Publisher is required")]
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category is required")]
        public string Category { get; set; }        
        [Range(1, 1000)]
        public override decimal Price
        {
            get;
            set;

        }


    }
```

I am expecting this data to come in my action method as the parameter but I always get as **null**

Answer (score 1):

I recreated the code and here goes my solution -

**Headers -** (There is a problem with your `content-type`)

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:1655
Content-Length: 103
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

**Request Body -**

```
{
"Title": "asasd",
"Author": "asaa",
"Publisher": "Asaas",
"Category": "asdasd",
"Price": "12"
}
```

Here is the screenshot of complete fiddler request -

[image]

Then I was able to get the `Book` in my Action -

[image]

Additional Information please check my below routes -

```
       public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80194/discussion-on-answer-by-ramiramilu-json-data-is-not-getting-serialized-correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DataContractJsonSerializer`

```
[DataContract]
public class Book : Product
{
    [DataMember]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Title is required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Author is required")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Publisher is required")]
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category is required")]
    public string Category { get; set; }  
    [DataMember]      
    [Range(1, 1000)]
    public override decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your Controller

```
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Book));
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonData))
{
    Book book = ser.ReadObject(ms) as Book;
}
```

Something like this should do it. Read up a bit on the DataContractJsonSeriailzer.

Comment: `jsonData` is null for me. too. `Something like this should do it` isn't an answar.

Comment: jsonData is just a variable. I never said that my Controller code was the complete controller.. You'd need to do some work yourself. jsonData is supposed to be the data you received.